# For what value of parameter $a\in \mathbb{R}$ is line $y=\frac{3}{2}x-2$ tangent of given curve

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, tangent-line

$$y=\frac{3}{2}x-2$$

$$y^2x+a=x^2+y^2$$

This is what I have so far. Tangent and curve are intersecting in $(0,-2)$ so

$$4*0+a=0+4 \Rightarrow a=4$$

I have to check $y'(0)=\frac{3}{2}$. I don't know how to derive curve because i get $y$ and $y'$. And if i don't get $y'(0)=\frac{3}{2}$, then $a$ doesn't exist?

Comment: Are you given that the tangent and curve should intersect at $(0,-2)$? Otherwise that seems arbitrary.

Comment: @Semiclassical I checked with Desmos. The given line and curve do intersect at (0,-2) when a = 4 but it's not a tangential intersection. This requires a discriminant calculation and I'll write an answer for this soon.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Differentiating the second equation with respect to $x$, you get $$y^2+2xyy'=2x+2yy'.$$ But the slope of $y=3x/2-2$ is $3/2$, so the value of $y'$ at the point of intersection should be $y'=3/2$ as well. Plugging this back in gives $$y^2+3xy=2x+3y,$$
and you want to find the intersection of this with $y=3x/2-2$. The rest is algebra.

---

For geometric clarity, here's Mathematica plots of the three curves discussed for the cases indicated by Parcly Taxel's answer:

[image]

The blue curve is the line $y=3x/2-2$, the orange curve is the intersecting curve (with $a=3$ in the first plot and $a=\frac{1684}{2187}$ in the second), and the green curve is the equation $y^2+3xy=2x+3y$. The point is that, for these values of $a$, all three curves intersect at a common point, and the blue and orange curves are tangent at this point.

Comment: I get two solutions. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(3x%2F2-2)%5E2%2B3x(3x%2F2-2)%3D2x%2B3(3x%2F2-2) , which one should I use? And where had a dissapeared, I think you have something wrong

Comment: Without further context, you'd use both. (They should be the same values found in Parcly Taxel's answer.

Comment: I get two solutions for $x$, not for $a$, in your answer, solution doesn't rely on $a$

Comment: Yes, it does: Once you've gotten $x$, you can find $y$ from $y=3x/2-2$. Then you plug that back into the second curve to find $a$. Hence, two values of $x$ means two values of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

The $x$-coordinates of the intersections of the line and curve for a given $a$ can be found by substituting the line's equation into the curve:
$$y^2x+a=x^2+y^2$$
$$y^2(x-1)-x^2+a=0$$
$$\left(\frac32x-2\right)^2(x-1)-x^2+a=0$$
$$\frac94x^3-\frac{37}4x^2+10x-(4-a)=0$$
For the intersection to be tangential, the discriminant of this equation must be zero, which will create a multiple root. The discriminant with respect to $x$ is
$$\Delta=-\frac1{16}(2187a^2-8209a+4944)$$
and this is zero when
$$a=3\text{ or }a=\frac{1648}{2187}$$
At these values of $a$, then, the given line is tangent to the curve.